# How to solve for $x^3$ relative to $(x-1)^3$

Tags: polynomials, cubics

There is probably a better way of asking this question.  There is a pretty simple formula to figure out $x^2$ from $(x-1)^2$.

$$x^2 = (x-1)^2 + x + (x-1)$$

You can see how easy this formula is here:

$$4^2 = 3^2 + 4 + 3 = 9 + 4 + 3 = 16$$

My question is this:  Is there a similar formula for figuring out cubes of numbers?  This is the best that I can come up with and it seems a little forced:

$$x^3 = (x-1)^3 + 2x^2 + (x-1)^2 + (-x)$$

Again, you can see here that it works:

$$4^3 = 3^3 + 2(4^2) + 3^2 + (-4) = 27 + 32 + 9 - 4 = 64$$

Maybe this is something that everybody already knows and I'll feel like an idiot, but if somebody has a cleaner equation for what I'm looking for here, please let me know.

Comment: $x^3 = (x-1)^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1$. Just expand $(x-1)^3$ and simply add/subtract terms until you are left with $x^3$.

Comment: Personally, I don't know any formula to find $x^3$ from $(x-1)^3$. I think the formula you gave is fine, in any case, square powers must be computed.

Comment: This alternative arrangement might be more to your taste: $x^3=(x-1)^3 + 2(x-1)^2 +x^2 +(x-1)$. All additions, anyway.

Comment: I'm kinda lost. How is it easier to do $3^2+4+3$  instead of  $4^2$?

Comment: From the answer by @Tim , how about $x^3 = (x-1)^3 + 3x(x-1) + 1$? You just need to deal with one extra $x$ and $(x-1)$.

Comment: You can also do this from @Tim 's  $(x-1)^3+(2x-1)^2-x(x-1)$ . Though it isn't completely in terms of $(x-1)$. And I don't understand how this makes it is easier to compute $x^3$.

Comment: @randomgirl Maybe the OP's idea is to find a way to remember how to calculate the difference between $x^3$ and $(x-1)^3$ without using calculators. For the difference between $x^2$ and $(x-1)^2$, it is easy to remember, because it is the sum of $x$ and $x-1$.

Comment: I just been so focused on "You can see how easy this formula is here:".

Comment: But maybe you are right.

Comment: OPs formula for calculating $x^2$ is not a formula using only the information about $(x-1)^2$ it is a formula in terms of $(x-1)^2$ *and* $x$. Since you have to put $x$ into the formula why not just do it easy: $x^2 = x\cdot x$ ?

Comment: $x^3-(x-1)^3=(x-(x-1))(x^2+x(x-1)+(x-1)^2)=x^2+x(x-1)+(x-1)^2$ by difference of cubes formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^3=((x-1)+1)^3=(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2+3(x-1)+1
$$
by the binomial formula.